# How to fetch data by joining tables and using where clause from another table

Tags: mysql

Let me explain the question with the following example:

This is how my MySQL database looks like:

table name: `general_info`

```
Movie_ID    Movie_Name
1           Iron Man
2           Superman
3           Batman
```

table name: `cast`

```
Movie_ID     Cast_Name              
1            Robert Downey Jr.      
1            Gwyneth Paltrow        

2            Henry Cavill           
2            Amy Adams              

3            Christian Bale         
3            Heath Ledger
```

Table name `production_companies`

```
Movie_ID       Production_name        
1              Marvel                 
1              Paramount              

2              Legendary Pictures     
2              DC Entertainment       

3              Snycopy
```

table name `user_cast_preference`

```
user_id     user_cast_name
1           Robert Downey Jr.
1           Gwyneth Paltrow 
1           Christian Bale 
1           Heath Ledger
```

table name `user_production_preference`

```
user_id        user_production_name
1              Marvel
1              Paraamount
1              Syncopy
```

---

---

Now, I want to fetch all movies which meet user's preference. In other words, fetch all movies, where user's preferred cast + preferred production company is in.

Here is the **expected result**

```
movie_id     movie_name    cast_name               production_name


1            Iron Man      Robert Downey Jr,       Marvel, 
                           Gwyneth Paltrow         Paramount

2            Batman        Christian Bale,         Syncopy
                           Heath Ledger
```

I only fetched Ironman and Batman and did not fetch superman, because at least one actor/production_company of the movie was in user's preferred list.

And not even a single actor or production company name was in superman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select movie_id,movie_name,cast_name,production_name
from general_info as g
  inner join cast as c on g.movie_id=c.movie_id
  inner join production_companies p on g.movie_id=p.movie_id
where c.cast_name in (select user_cast_name from user_cast_prefrence)
```

Try this query..hope it helps and mark it answer

Comment: Also you forgot 2 things in your query. Line one: it will be `select general_info.movie_id, movie_name.....` and line 4: `production_companies as p on g.movie_id...`

Comment: I also did group_concat on cast_name and production_name and group by movie_name.